# How to group values based on condition in java

Tags: java

I have some values return from database as a result set like following

```
**resource_name         menu_name       menu_group_name**
DepartmentAction        Department      Admin Operation
PositionAction          Position        Admin Operation
FoodHabitAction         FoodHabits      Admin Operation
ReligiousAction         Religious       Admin Operation
NationalitiesAction     Nationlities    Admin Operation
```

I would like to group resource_name and menu_mane based on menu_group_name
some thing like the following

```
 if the menu_group_name is same than group all the corresponding
    resource_name and menu_mane against to menu_group_name .
```

UPDATE  :

```
 public Map<String,List> getMenuForLoggedinRole(int roleid){
        Map<String,List> menuListMap = new LinkedHashMap<String,List>();
        List<MenuListViewModel> menuNamesList = new ArrayList<MenuListViewModel>();
        MenuListViewModel menuViewModel;
        Connection connection = getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                ps = connection.prepareStatement(" select ar.resource_name,ar.menu_name,mg.menu_group_name "
                        + " from m_application_resources as ar,"
                        + " m_menu_groups as mg,m_access_matrix as amatrix "
                        + " where ar.resourceid = amatrix.resourceid and amatrix.roleid=?");
                ps.setInt(1, roleid);
                rs = ps.executeQuery();
                if(rs.next()) {
                   String menu_group_name = rs.getString("menu_group_name");
                   String resource_name = rs.getString("resource_name");
                   String menu_name = rs.getString("menu_name");
                   if(menuListMap.containsKey(menu_group_name)){
                       menuNamesList =(List) menuListMap.get(menu_group_name);
                       menuViewModel = new MenuListViewModel();
                       menuViewModel.setResource_name(resource_name);
                       menuViewModel.setMenu_name(menu_name);
                       menuNamesList.add(menuViewModel);
                       menuListMap.put(menu_group_name, menuNamesList);
                   }else{
                       menuViewModel = new MenuListViewModel();
                       menuViewModel.setResource_name(resource_name);
                       menuViewModel.setMenu_name(menu_name);
                       menuNamesList.add(menuViewModel);
                       menuListMap.put(menu_group_name, menuNamesList);
                   }
                } 
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }finally {
                try {
                    closeConnection(connection, rs, ps);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    //use logger here
                }
            }
        }

        printMap(menuListMap);
        return menuListMap;
    }
```

when i printed and saw only one value is getting printed others are not.
Please help me how to do this.
i know that it is very simple needs your help.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create some class,CustomClass, with members `resource_name` and `menu_name`

now create a `map<String, List<CustomClass>>`

iterate over resultset and keep adding data to map

`menu_group_name` will be your key and customclass you have created will be value, while putting data in map, check if that key exists, if yes retrive list and add new customclass to it else create a new list with your customclass and add put key value pair

Comment: i don't know what your printMap function is doing, but one thing i can see that you are creating menuNamesList outside try, bring it in if and else block

Answer (score 0):

i think it is possible to do some code like this

```
class Pair {
                String v1;
                String v2;
                Pair(String value1, String value2){
                    v1=  value1;
                    v2 = value2;
                }
            }
            Map<String , List<Pair>> maps = new HashMap<>();
            List<Pair> keypair = new ArrayList<Pair>();
            keypair.add(new Pair("", ""));
            maps.put("Hello", keypair);
            maps.get("Hello").add(new Pair("", ""));
```